# How to create an installer that updates a previous version with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publish, publishing

We have an application made in C# with Visual Studio. The installer of this application is made with Publish of Visual Studio.

If the app is already installed on a PC, the installer warns that an application is already installed and to update the application to a new version, the previous version must be uninstalled, but that implies that a database in SQL containing it is deleted the project.

To solve the problem we create another application that downloads only the new *.exe file of the application and replaces the previous one and that way the 'updates' of our app have worked correctly.

But now we have added new functionality that previous installers don't have and just replacing the *.exe file is not the solution.

My question is: How can I create a Visual Studio installer that doesn't delete the database that I mentioned?

At the moment the cumbersome solution to this problem is to restore the database in another part of the PC, uninstall the old version of the PC, install the new version and paste the database.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

[Wix](https://wixtoolset.org/) allows you complete control over what is installed or updated when you run the installation process.